# Java: printing custom (Printable) page with header and footer

Tags: java, printing, header, customization, footer

I know that some components (JTable, JTextArea) in Java have own way to pass to them header and footer of the page.
Is it any easy way to print a page based on Printable implemented by myself or should i position them by myself (eg. in overriden print(...)  method of Printable interface)?
This Printable class as an input recieves pack of plaint text and thats all.
Of course at the end i can put everything in JTextArea, but i wouldn't like to do this if there is some other way.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position them in your overridden  print() method.

```
public class TestReport implements Printable
{
    //Here is where we set up the class variables.
    private int numberOfPages = 0;              //numberOfPages -- How many pages we will be printing.
    private int headerLines = 0;                //headerLines -- How many lines are in the header.
    private int footerLines = 0;                //footerLines -- How many lines are in the footer.
    private int bodyLines = 0;                  //bodyLines -- How many lines we've added to the body of the report.
    private boolean useDefaultFooter = false;   //useDefaultFooter -- If we are to use the default footer instead of a custom one.
    private int fontSize = 10;                  //fontSize -- The size of the font to use, in points. The default is 10pt.
    private Vector header = new Vector();       //header -- The vector containing the header text.
                                                //Each item in the vector is a line on the header.
    private Vector body = new Vector();         //body -- The vector containing the body text.
    private Vector footer = new Vector();       //footer -- The vector containing the footer.

    //The constructor does not need to do anything.

    /**
     * Create a new instance or TestReport
     */
    public TestReport() 
    {

    }

    /**
     * Prints the final report after the information has been added.
     */
    public void printReport()
    {

        //Get the number of lines in the header, body, and footer. If we're using the default footer, it's only one line long.

        headerLines = header.size();
        bodyLines = body.size();
        if (useDefaultFooter == true) {
            footerLines = 1;
        } else {
            footerLines = footer.size();
        }
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat landscape = printerJob.defaultPage();
        landscape.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        printerJob.setPrintable(TestReport.this, landscape);

        printerJob.printDialog();

        try {
            printerJob.print();
        } catch (Exception PrintException) {}
    }

    public void addHeaderLine (String headerLine)
    {
        header.addElement(headerLine);
    }

    public void addBodyLine (String bodyLine)
    {
        body.addElement(bodyLine);
    }

    public void addFooterLine (String footerLine)
    {
        footer.addElement(footerLine);
    }

    public void setFontSize(int fontSize)
    {
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }

    public void useDefaultFooter()
    {
        useDefaultFooter = true;
    } 


    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException 
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        Font myFont = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        g2.setFont(myFont);

        int fontHeight = g2.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
        int fontDescent = g2.getFontMetrics().getDescent();

        double pageHeight = pageFormat.getHeight();
        double pageWidth = pageFormat.getWidth();

        int lineHeight = fontHeight + fontDescent;

        int linesPerPage = (int)((pageHeight - 72 - 72) / lineHeight);

        int bodyLinesPerPage = linesPerPage - headerLines - footerLines;

        int numberOfPages = (int)Math.ceil((double)bodyLines / bodyLinesPerPage);

        if (pageIndex >= numberOfPages)
        {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        //Start at one inch down, one inch accross
        int currentY = 72 + lineHeight;
        int currentX = 72;

        //Draw the header
        for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++) 
        {
            g2.drawString(header.get(i), currentX, currentY);
            currentY = currentY + lineHeight;
        }
        //Draw the body
        for (int i = bodyLinesPerPage * pageIndex; i < (bodyLinesPerPage * (pageIndex + 1)) ; i++ )
        {
            if (i < body.size()){
                g2.drawString(body.get(i), currentX, currentY);
            }
            currentY = currentY + lineHeight;
        }
        if (useDefaultFooter == true) 
        {
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            int todayYear = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
            int todayMonth = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int todayDay = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

            String theMonth = "0" + todayMonth;
            String theDay   = "0" + todayDay;

            g2.drawString("SYSTEM DATE: " + todayYear + "-" + theMonth.substring
                          (theMonth.length() - 2) + "-" + 
                          theDay.substring(theDay.length() - 2) 
                          + " | PAGE " + (pageIndex + 1) 
                          + " OF " + numberOfPages, currentX, currentY);
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < footer.size(); i++)
            {
                g2.drawString(footer.get(i), currentX, currentY);
                currentY = currentY + lineHeight;
            }
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;       
    }
}
```